# In Android manifest, how to require at least one of two pieces of hardware?

Tags: android, xml, bluetooth, nfc

For example, if writing an app involving wireless data transfer between two devices, this can be done through either Bluetooth or NFC. So, in the Manifest, how would you denote that the app requires at least one of these two? I have little experience with XML, so I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Is the implementation different based on the differences between the hardware? If so, you should consider creating two different "flavors" in Android Studio. Each flavor will have its own manifest describing which hardware is supported.

Comment: It would not be an entirely separate application; if your device has both Bluetooth and NFC, you could choose either one to use for the transfer, but if your device does not have NFC, then (obviously) you would only be able to choose to use Bluetooth.

Comment: How do you access the hardware in your app? Is there different code for accessing NFC compared to accessing Bluetooth?

Comment: I haven't written it yet, I assumed the Manifest would be the first step

Comment: OIC. I assume that you will have different code for each type of hardware. My suggestion is to implement this using the "flavors" feature in Android Studio. You will have some shared code in the `main` folder. The code specific to NFC and to BlueTooth will be in separate folders. Each of these will also have manifests with the correct `<uses-permissions>` tag. There will also be a common manifest in the `main` folder. This means you will build two separate APK files. You can upload both to Google Play as a single app. From the user's point of view there is only one app.

Comment: Perhaps there are other solutions as well. This is what comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [build variants in Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants). This feature allows you to easily share code as well as provide custom the code and configuration for different variations of the same app. You will need to create two "product flavors", one for NFC and the other for BlueTooth. The common code and AndroidManifest will be in the `main` folder of your Android Studio project. The customizations will be in separate folders for each variant. This includes AndroidManifest files with different `<uses-permission>` tags. You will probably also have different code to actually implement your hardware-dependent features.

When you are ready to publish to Google Play, you will need to build two different APK files, one for NFC support and one for Bluetooth. You can upload both APKs to the same Google Play app. (See [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).) From the user's point of view, there is only one app.